# Rails-style test method in plain Ruby with just Minitest?

Tags: ruby, testing, minitest

Rails adds a `test` method enabling one to write:

```
class FooTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  test "the truth" do
    assert true
  end

end
```

How might one enable the identical expressiveness in a plain Ruby test suite with only Minitest? Instead of:

```
class FooTest

  def test_the_truth
    assert true
  end

end
```

or "spec-style" like:

```
describe Foo
  it "is true" do
    assert true
  end
end
```

I'd like to be able to:

```
class FooTest

  test "the truth" do
    assert true
  end

end
```

Or use `test` instead of `it` in the "spec-style."

Comment: Minitest has its own structure for writing tests. It seems like you are trying to reinvent the wheel here

Comment: Hm... I'd just like to be able to use strings instead of `test_name_here`. For example `test_tuple_(0, 0, 0)_is_special` isn't a good method name.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question. I am not sure